# Matlab error using filtfilt() 'Data length must be larger than 18 samples."

Tags: matlab, filter, neural-network

I'm making a neural network that works with wavelets but I have got the following error:

> Error using filtfilt>getCoeffsAndInitialConditions (line 182)
>   Data length must be larger than 18 samples.
>
> Error in filtfilt (line 97)
>   [b,a,zi,nfact,L] = getCoeffsAndInitialConditions(b,a,Npts);
>
> Error in decimate (line 136)
>       odata = filtfilt(b,a,idata);
>
> Error in ENGNeuralNetwork (line 56)
>       decdatae(ch,trial,:)=squeeze(decimate(cD1(ch,trial,:),32));

I am a bit confused about what I should be changing, as I'm sure these are all related errors. This is the code that it is referring to for line 56:

```
for ch=1:2
    for trial=1:10
    decdatae(ch,trial,:)=squeeze(decimate(cD1(ch,trial,:),32));

    end 
end
```

and this is the code for line 97:

```
for runs=1:10 

    % Create a neural net with 100 hidden neurons
    net=newff(P,T,1000,{'tansig','logsig'},'traingdx');
    net.TrainParam.epochs=1000;
    net.TrainParam.goal=0.04;
    net.TrainParam.min_grad=1e-20; %line 97
    net.TrainParam.show=3000;
    net.divideParam.trainRatio=0.6;
    net.divideParam.valRatio=0;
    net.divideParam.testRatio=0.4;
```

I'd be grateful if anyone could give me a heads up of how to sort this.

Thanks

Comment: The error detected in `filtfilt (line 97)` is in the build-in function `filtfilt`, not in your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is at the very beginning of the help text of filtfilt:

```matlab
%   The length of the input X must be more than three times the filter
%   order, defined as max(length(B)-1,length(A)-1).
```

You can see that using `open filtfilt` or `help filtfilt`. It's weird, but you won't see that with `doc filtfilt`.

I don't know why that requirement for the data length.

Answer (score 0):

Note that usually, Matlab errors should be read starting from the bottom. So what you would like to understand is

> Error in ENGNeuralNetwork (line 56) decdatae(ch,trial,:)=squeeze(decimate(cD1(ch,trial,:),32));

When you are calling `decimate`at line 56, you are [decimating](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/decimate.html) your data by a factor of 32! Is means that your actual length of your data is divided by 32:

> y = decimate(x,r) reduces the sample rate of x, the input signal, by a factor of r, **length(y) = ceil(length(x)/r)**

We don't know the original size of your data but it might be a problem if the length of `cD1(ch,trial,:)` is too small. You should check the size of `cD1`.

Then, `according` to decimate documentation:

> For better results when r is greater than 13, divide r into smaller factors and call decimate several times.